# What is the Difference Between 49.toString() Vs 49..toString()?

Tags: javascript

I was just playing around javascript toString method, then when i tried the number.toString() it gave me error, but when i tried number..toString() it gave me the result that i was expecting for the first code.

```
1. Can any one explain what is the reason for this / What is the difference here ?
2. why is 49.toString() is giving me error ? does that mean number has no toString() method ?  
3. What is happening here exactly ?
```

**JS Code**

```
49.toString(); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

49..toString(); //"49"
```

Comment: `49..toString` means `49.0.toString` which is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The period is being parsed as a decimal point. That's why you're getting a syntax error. In the double period case you are calling `toString` on a floating point number not the integer 49.